# Is initializing a reference of type "int &" (not const-qualified) with a value of type "bool" some hack?

Tags: c++, gcc, reference

I came accros this c++ code [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3638/):

```
  // round alternate
  // Bias: none for sequential calls
  bool _is_up = false;
  template <typename FloatType>
  FloatType roundalternate( const FloatType& value, int& is_up = _is_up )
    {
    if ((is_up != is_up))
      return roundhalfup( value );
    return roundhalfdown( value );
    }
```

And it confuses me, how is this supposed to work? How is this supposed to make an alternate call on each call of this function?

Is this code just plain wrong, or is it supposed to work due to some compiler weirdness?
It seems to have compiled fine with g++ but I can't reproduce this at the moment.
icc is not accepting it:

```
rounding.h(183): error: a reference of type "int &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "bool"
FloatType roundalternate0( const FloatType& value, int& is_up = _is_up )
                                                                  ^
```

**Update**
g++ does not seem to accept it either (update to clarify after Ben Voight's answer: g++ can compile the plain file (which icc can not), but fails if you try to invoke without a second argument)

```
bla.h: In function ‘FloatType rounding::roundalternate(const FloatType&, int&) [with FloatType = char*]’:
bla.h:220:35: error: could not convert ‘rounding::_is_up’ from ‘bool’ to ‘int&’
   rounding::roundalternate(argv[0])
```

[Other people](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tuxedo-tools-users/-b2VUqRlRSc/S3Tf9wzJ3XAJ) are reporting problems with clang as well

Relevance: I'm trying to compile [cufflinks](http://cufflinks.cbcb.umd.edu/) with the intel compiler, and it is failing because this code is in there.

I have no idea how cufflinks could have compiled before with this in it.

update2:
Cufflinks compiled fine with g++, not with icc, I've contacted the maintainers, and they have removed the offending piece of code in newer versions.

Comment: `if ((is_up != is_up))` looks fishy -- is that from the original code, or should one of the arguments be `_is_up`?

Comment: Are you sure? I get this error: `error: could not convert ‘_is_up’ from ‘bool’ to ‘int&’`

Comment: In any case, GCC 4.7.3 doesn't grok this.

Comment: @larsmans: Agree that's fishy. Given that `is_up` is supposed to flipflop (this is round *alternate*), I think that should read `if ((is_up = !is_up))`.

Comment: Ah, of course! Pretty nasty, that.

Comment: And the meta-question: why didn't the author of this code solve this using a `static` local variable instead of hacking around with references? of the wrong type? to a global variable?

Comment: @H2CO3: So that multiple calls to the function could use independent state, if the caller chooses to supply his own state variable.

Comment: @BenVoigt Aham. Wrong approach, I guess, at least by using an `int &`. Even if it compiles, it is confusing.

Comment: @H2CO3: The types need to match.  Either both `bool`, or both `int`, will work.

Comment: @H2CO3: Also, a `static` variable would be separate for each distinct `FloatType`.  Here, all default calls share the same state variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code obviously is trouble.  `int&` cannot bind to an lvalue of type `bool`, and cannot bind to an rvalue resulting from a conversion.  However, it also compiles without error.

This is because, unlike normal functions, semantic analysis for default arguments in template functions occurs only "when the function is called in a context that requires the value of the default argument", explained in 8.3.6p5, 14.7.1p3, and 14.7.1p13 of the Standard.

That means the compile error will only occur when other code calls this function without providing an actual argument for the second parameter.

Comment: Well it is not compiling with the intel compiler, I guess it is more strict then needed? I probably need a flag to tell it not to do this.

Comment: @Jens: Does the error occur at the template definition, or at the point of use?  Breaking compilation for a template that is never instantiated is a pretty serious compiler nonconformity.  Only a few checks are supposed to be done during Phase 1 of template compilation, most are required to occur only when instantiated (Phase 2).

Comment: at template definition, I believe there is no point of use (This is not my own code I'm trying to debug, I'll patch the function out and try again)

Comment: @JensTimmerman: Well, the Standard wording has changed a bit since C++03.  I think what the compiler is doing could be defended under the old wording, but no longer.  You should probably send Intel a bug report, since this is something of an unusual case.

Comment: @JensTimmerman: The line in G++'s error message, `rounding::roundalternate(argv[0])`, certainly looks like usage.  And utilizes the default argument.  That should make all compilers fail.

Comment: correct, g++ only fails on usage, this is when compiling a different file I fabricated to test it out.  icc fails where g++ does not fail.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41557/discussion-between-jens-timmerman-and-ben-voigt)